# Trouble with piping through sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, pipe

I am having trouble piping through sed. Once I have piped output to sed, I cannot pipe the output of sed elsewhere.

```
wget -r -nv http://127.0.0.1:3000/test.html
```

Outputs:

```
2010-03-12 04:41:48 URL:http://127.0.0.1:3000/test.html [99/99] -> "127.0.0.1:3000/test.html" [1]
2010-03-12 04:41:48 URL:http://127.0.0.1:3000/robots.txt [83/83] -> "127.0.0.1:3000/robots.txt" [1]
2010-03-12 04:41:48 URL:http://127.0.0.1:3000/shop [22818/22818] -> "127.0.0.1:3000/shop.29" [1]
```

I pipe the output through sed to get a clean list of URLs:

```
wget -r -nv http://127.0.0.1:3000/test.html 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -v ERROR | sed 's/^.*URL:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/g'
```

Outputs:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/test.html
http://127.0.0.1:3000/robots.txt
http://127.0.0.1:3000/shop
```

I would like to then dump the output to file, so I do this:

```
wget -r -nv http://127.0.0.1:3000/test.html 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -v ERROR | sed 's/^.*URL:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/g' > /tmp/DUMP_FILE
```

I interrupt the process after a few seconds and check the file, yet it is empty.

Interesting, the following yields no output (same as above, but piping sed output through cat):

```
wget -r -nv http://127.0.0.1:3000/test.html 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -v ERROR | sed 's/^.*URL:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/g' | cat
```

Why can I not pipe the output of sed to another program like cat?

Comment: sed should work fine with pipes, for example: echo "foo" | sed 's/foo/bar/g' >/tmp/foo works fine for me. Does adding the -u option to sed make a difference? Alternately try letting the process finish to completion before checking the file. sed may just be doing too much internal buffering of results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When sed is writing to another process or to a file, it will buffer data.

Try adding the `--unbuffered` options to sed.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use awk. since your URL appears in field 3, you can use $3, and you can remove the grep as well.

```
awk '!/ERROR/{sub("URL:","",$3);print $3}' file
```

Comment: why not start from today ? :)