# Looking for linux application or command to pipe images to using grep and sed

Tags: linux, image, sed, grep, piping

I am trying to view an image automatically on a site. The following will *download* the desired image file successfully:

```
wget $(wget -O - myURL | grep myPattern | sed myScript)
```

When I try piping to feh using

```
wget -O - $(wget -O - myURL | grep myPattern | sed myScript) | feh
```

I get

```
Cannot write to `-' (Broken pipe).
```

Doing

```
wget -O - $(wget -O - myURL | grep myPattern | sed myScript)
```

will output a lot of gibberish to stdout which I am assuming is the image file, so my conclusion is that feh can not read from a pipe, and looking at the man page seems to indicate this is true. Can this be solved somehow or do I need another tool? If I do, I would prefere as small a tool as possible.

I had a look at a question resembling this slightly, [Trouble with piping through sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427338/trouble-with-piping-through-sed) but not sure how similar this is. I did try the --unbuffered option with sed, it didnt work and I am not sure I would understand it if it did work.

Comment: After playing around with it, I found that it won't accept data from stdin in any way.

Answer (score 4):

ImageMagick's `display` can take images from stdin.

Answer (score 3):

Syntax:

```
-f, --filelist file
```

If `file` is `"-"`, `feh` will read the `filelist` from its standard input.

So:

```
feh -f-
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running `feh -` instead of `feh`?

Comment: Tried both but no luck. Looks like feh doesn't support reading images from stdin